# Visual Studio displaying wrong errors

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a function in my Javascript that causes errors in the function and in other functions as well, but the code compile just fine.If I remove the function, all of the red underlined errors are disappearing. I tried cleaning/rebuilding/restarting the computer but nothing changes.
Here's the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verifyRange(name, date, currentValue) {
    switch (name) {
        case "FC_OAT":
        case "Forecast Air Temp. (°C)":
            if (currentValue != null && currentValue < <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinOAT"]%> || currentValue > <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxOAT"]%>)   {                     
                   createAnnotation("Forecast Air Temp. (°C)","Forecast Air Temp. (°C)" + " \n<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"OutOfBounds") %>\n[MIN:<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinOAT"]%>, MAX:<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxOAT"]%>] \n<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"ValueIs") %> " + currentValue + "°C",date);                   
            }
        break*;*
        *case* "OAT":
        case "Air Temp. (°C)":
            if (currentValue != null && currentValue < <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinOAT"]%> || currentValue > <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxOAT"]%>)   {                     
                   createAnnotation("Air Temp. (°C)","Air Temp. (°C)" + " \n<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"OutOfBounds") %>\n[MIN:<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinOAT"]%>, MAX:<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxOAT"]%>] \n<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"ValueIs") %> " + currentValue + "°C",date);                   
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The *;* gets error : can't have 'break' outside of loop

The  *case* gets error : Expected '}'

After this function I have this code

```
 $(document).ready(function *(*) {           
   alert('hello');
 }*)*;
 </script>
```

The *(* gets error : Expected identifier

The *)* gets error : Syntax error

Of course, the ** are used to show where the red underline is done by visual studio, I don't have this in my code.

My question is : Is there a way to have server tags inside an if without breaking visualstudio? Is it a bad way of coding to do so?

Comment: your quotes in `createAnnotation` function call are messed up. What does this function take as parameters?

Comment: they are here but not in visual studio, and commenting the createannotation call doesn`t remove the wrong error messages

Comment: did you comment the if too?

Comment: yes,I'm assuming the if causes the problem hence my question : `Is there a way to have server tags inside an if without breaking visualstudio?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refactor your code so the server values assigned to js vars and substitute them in the if statement:

```
    var minOAT = <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinOAT"]%>;
    var maxOAT = <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxOAT"]%>;
    var outOfBoundsString = "<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"OutOfBounds") %>";
    var valueIsString = "<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(Session["culture"].ToString(),"ValueIs") %>";

    if (currentValue != null && (currentValue < minOAT || currentValue > maxOAT))   {                     
          createAnnotation(
             "Forecast Air Temp. (°C)",
             "Forecast Air Temp. (°C) \n" + 
                 outOfBoundsString + "\n" +
                 "[MIN:" + minOAT + ", MAX:" + maxOAT + "]\n" + 
                 valueIsString + " " + currentValue + "°C", 
             date);
    }
```

This should make the code look less messy and hopefully the error will disappear.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that would not make me want to do this since I have 50+ case but oh well, at least it works